# javascript - split on plus and minus

Tags: javascript

How do I split a var, which I got from a text input on a "+", "-", "x" and "^"?

JavaScript

```
function integralinput() {
var a = document.getElementById("input").value;
console.log(a);
var b = a.split("x" + "^" + "+" + "-");
console.log(b);
}
```

html:

```
<input id="input" type="text"><label for="function">Funktion</label>
<input type="button" onclick="integralinput()" value="Run">
```

Comment: You can split on regexes instead of strings... Have you tried a.split(/[x^+-]/)

Comment: beside the obvious, what do you want do after splitting with the array? do you need the operators as well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a regex

```
var b = a.split(/[x^+-]/)
```

Comment: this works for some reason without the "g" (global modifier). why? i would assumed that it would only find the first occurrence. is "g" the default modifier in js?

Comment: `split` is always global.

Comment: @BenYitzhaki I was just checking the same thing. I think it is a feature of `split()` itself, as you would generally want to split on every occurrence, rather than just the first.

Comment: I would guess it is comparing each character with the separator argument rather than using the separator argument to find characters to split on.

Comment: It works, but the array has some vars, which are empty. I don't know if it's the "x", or the "^" which is being replaced with  "".

Comment: You need to be careful on the order of characters in the regex as the ^ and - have special meaning if placed in the correct position.  ^ at the beginning means not matching, and - in the middle is a range operator.

For instance, "10+20-3x5^6".split(/[^x+-]/) results in ["", "", "+", "", "-", "x", "", "", ""] which sounds like what you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only number you can use like this

```js
function integralinput() {
var a = document.getElementById("input").value;
var b = a.match(/\d+/g).map(Number);
console.log(b);
}
```

```html
<input value="10+20-3x5^6" id="input" type="text"><label for="function">Funktion</label>
<input type="button" onclick="integralinput()" value="Run">
```